# Ruby merge duplicates in string

Tags: ruby, string, duplicates, concatenation

If I have a string like this

```
str =<<END
7312357006,1.121
3214058234,3456
7312357006,1234
1324958723,232.1
3214058234,43.2
3214173443,234.1
6134513494,23.2
7312357006,11.1
END
```

If a number in the first value shows up again, I want to add their second values together. So the final string would look like this

```
7312357006,1246.221
3214058234,3499.2
1324958723,232.1
3214173443,234.1
6134513494,23.2
```

If the final output is an array that's fine too.

Comment: Sounds good, go for it! :-)

Comment: I trust you don't mind the minor edit I did. By creating a valid string object (you had a picture of a string, which I expect was the reason for the downvote) and assigning a variable to it, readers can cut-and-paste to test their answers, and can refer to the variable (`str`) in answers and comments without having to define it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this in Ruby. One particularly terse way is to use `String#scan`:

```
str = <<END
7312357006,1.121
3214058234,3456
7312357006,1234
1324958723,232.1
3214058234,43.2
3214173443,234.1
6134513494,23.2
7312357006,11.1
END

data = Hash.new(0)
str.scan(/(\d+),([\d.]+)/) {|k,v| data[k] += v.to_f }
p data
# => { "7312357006" => 1246.221,
#      "3214058234" => 3499.2,
#      "1324958723" => 232.1,
#      "3214173443" => 234.1,
#      "6134513494" => 23.2 }
```

This uses the regular expression `/(\d+),([\d.]+)/` to extract the two values from each line. The block is called with each pair as arguments, which are then merged into the hash.

This could also be written as a single expression using `each_with_object`:

```
data = str.scan(/(\d+),([\d.]+)/)
         .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(k,v), hsh| hsh[k] += v.to_f }
# => (same as above)
```

There are likewise many ways to print the result, but here are a couple I like:

```
puts data.map {|kv| kv.join(",") }.join("\n")
# => 7312357006,1246.221
#    3214058234,3499.2
#    1324958723,232.1
#    3214173443,234.1
#    6134513494,23.2

# or:
puts data.map {|k,v| "#{k},#{v}\n" }.join
# => (same as above)
```

You can [see all of these in action on repl.it](https://repl.it/@jrunning/ThatFrightenedNlp).

---

**Edit:** Although I don't recommend either of these for the sake of readability, here's more just for kicks (requires Ruby 2.4+):

```
data = str.lines.group_by {|s| s.slice!(/(\d+),/); $1 }
         .transform_values {|a| a.sum(&:to_f) }
```

...or, to going straight to a string:

```
puts str.lines.group_by {|s| s.slice!(/(\d+),/); $1 }
       .map {|k,vs| "#{k},#{vs.sum(&:to_f)}\n" }.join
```

Since repl.it is stuck on Ruby 2.3: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY7basJAEIbv9ym2WkqCy5g9JFFr79rbPoEQ1hpLak7sISBJnj2dCAW97cAMzPDN///GH6/TZJ2hb3S///h8J6nkQsZpFCWMAxecSMFVFG@EVEyqOHkA8Ei4FGobb1IhmZACHh6UBHHbeSqVmgGFQMJRCHur8IDAvSJ6kjkGOWmnMRRGg7KocwvfpvFtdrzSfrADtWDL4it/CtbB4bQK2Tp8pc@cjoT@FTija3tuTJV1uvS5xUc9UA3WV8HLzjXZOUS@pbMTab2z5Db/bQmVbpG8sA7hxbK/jGzZd/bebzzUCzrCT1PU0/QL)

Comment: Jordan, see my edit to the question, which allows you to remove the definition of `str`.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using [each_with_object](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_object), as below:

```
str = "7312357006,1.121
       3214058234,3456
       7312357006,1234
       1324958723,232.1
       3214058234,43.2
       3214173443,234.1
       6134513494,23.2
       7312357006,11.1"

# convert the string into nested pairs of floats
# to briefly summarise the steps: split entries by newline, strip whitespace, split by comma, convert to floats
arr = str.split("\n").map(&:strip).map { |el| el.split(",").map(&:to_f) }

result = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |el, hash| 
  hash[el.first] += el.last
end

# => {7312357006.0=>1246.221, 3214058234.0=>3499.2, 1324958723.0=>232.1, 3214173443.0=>234.1, 6134513494.0=>23.2}

# You can then call `to_a` on result if you want:
result.to_a

# => [[7312357006.0, 1246.221], [3214058234.0, 3499.2], [1324958723.0, 232.1], [3214173443.0, 234.1], [6134513494.0, 23.2]]
```

`each_with_object` iterates through each pair of data, providing them with access to an accumulator (in this the hash). By following this approach, we can add each entry to the hash, and add together the totals if they appear more than once.

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: Consider using `each_with_object` instead of `reduce` to avoid ugly trailing `hash`: `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |el, hash| hash[el.first] += el.last } }`.

Comment: _That's_ the clear use case for `each_with_object` I've been looking for. I've called `hash.tap...` far too many times while using `reduce`. Thanks @mudasobwa - have updated my answer.

Comment: It's worth nothing that `.map(&:strip)` is necessary here only because of the leading spaces in the input.

Comment: See my edit to the question, which allows you to remove the definition of `str`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine(str)
  str.each_line.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |s,h|
    k,v = s.split(',')        
    h.update(k=>v.to_f) { |k,o,n| o+n }
  end.reduce('') { |s,kv_pair| s << "%s,%g\n" % kv_pair }
end 

puts combine str
7312357006,1246.22
3214058234,3499.2
1324958723,232.1
3214173443,234.1
6134513494,23.2
```

Notes:

- using [String#each_line](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-each_line) is preferable to `str.split("\n")` as the former returns an enumerator whereas the latter returns a temporary array. Each element generated by the enumerator is line of `str` that (unlike the elements of `str.split("\n")`) ends with a newline character, but that is of no concern.
- see [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), specifically when a default value (here `0`) is used. If a hash has been defined `h = Hash.new(0)` and `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value, zero (`h` is not changed). When Ruby encounters the expression `h[k] += 1`, the first thing she does is expand it to `h[k] = h[k] + 1`. If `h` has been defined with a default value of zero, and `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right of the equality (*syntactic sugar*<sup>1</sup> for `h.[](k)`) returns zero.
- see [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`). `h.update(k=>v.to_f)` is syntactic sugar for `h.update({ k=>v.to_f })`
- see [Kernel#sprint](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for explanations of the formatting directives `%s` and `%g`.
- the receiver for the expression `reduce('') { |s,kv_pair| s << "%s,%g\n" % kv_pair }` (in the penultimate line), is the following hash.

```
   {"7312357006"=>1246.221, "3214058234"=>3499.2, "1324958723"=>232.1,
    "3214173443"=>234.1, "6134513494"=>23.2}
```

<sup>1 *Syntactic sugar* is a shortcut allowed by Ruby.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Implemented this solution as hash was giving me issues:

```
d = []
s.split("\n").each do |line|
  x = 0
  q = 0
  dup = false
  line.split(",").each do |data|
    if x == 0 and d.include? data then dup = true ; q = d.index(data) elsif x == 0 then d << data end
    if x == 1 and dup == false then d << data end
    if x == 1 and dup == true then d[q+1] = "#{'%.2f' % (d[q+1].to_f + data.to_f).to_s}" end
    if x == 2 and dup == false then d << data end
    x += 1
  end
end

x = 0
s = ""

d.each do |val|
  if x == 0 then s << "#{val}," end
  if x == 1 then s << "#{val}\n ; x = 0" end
  x += 1
end

puts(s)
```

Comment: I have to ask... why `"".index("")`? Also, if none of the other answers solved your problem, you should probably un-accept the one you accepted (and, I suggest, leave a comment describing *how* it didn't work, so that its author can help you fix it, because your solution seems very complex).

Comment: new to ruby and not sure how to save an index like this as I wanted to call it in different iterations of the line.split(",").each

Comment: `"".index("")` will *always* return `0`, because the index of an empty string in an empty string is always `0`.

Comment: I would provide more data about why hash wasn't working but the input really shouldn't be shared.

Comment: I was just using it as a place holder for q, which was called in the loop

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "place holder," but that line can be replaced with `q = 0`.

Comment: If this code is working for you, I would recommend posting it on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). They will help you clean it up.

Comment: Grr @JordanRunning my accepted answer :P Lyres, I'd strongly suggest persisting with one of the answers suggested - they're a lot more readable and idiomatic Ruby. Of all the options I actually think Jordan's two line approaches using `scan` are pretty nifty.